# Javascript if statement not working for form compare

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a bootstrap form and i'm handling it with js.
but having problem cause if statement is not working correctly.

if you run the code you will see that the if statement that is comparing the second and third field is not working correctly
for second and third field in case 9 and a number below 9 it works but if you enter for example 10 and 5 for second and third field it wont work true.
Also if you enter 5 and 10 for second and third field it must return the error but it works.
any idea?

```js
function mcalculate() {
    var mainPrice = document.forms["disc"]["price"].value;
    var productPercentage = document.forms["disc"]["t-per"].value;
    var customerPercentage = document.forms["disc"]["c-per"].value;
    var productCount = document.forms["disc"]["count"].value;
    var runProject = true;
    if (isNaN(mainPrice)){
        document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "قیمت کالا باید عدد باشد";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (mainPrice<1){
        document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "قیمت کالا باید عدد و مثبت باشد";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (isNaN(productPercentage ) || isNaN(customerPercentage)){
        document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "درصد باید عدد باشد";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (productPercentage>100 || productPercentage<0){
        document.getElementById("error4").innerHTML = "تخفیف شما بین 0 تا 100 نیست";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error4").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (customerPercentage>100 || customerPercentage<0 ){
        document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML = "تخفیف مشتری بین 0 تا 100 نیست. ";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (isNaN(customerPercentage)){
        document.getElementById("error6").innerHTML = "درصد باید عدد باشد"
        runProject = false;
    }
    else if(customerPercentage > productPercentage){
        document.getElementById("error6").innerHTML = "تخفیف مشتری از تخفیف شما بیشتر است";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error6").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (isNaN(productCount)){
        document.getElementById("error7").innerHTML = "تعداد کالا باید عدد باشد";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error7").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (productCount<1){
        document.getElementById("error8").innerHTML = "تعداد کالا باید عدد و مثبت باشد";
        runProject = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error8").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (runProject==true){
        document.getElementById("calResult").innerHTML = "das"
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("calResult").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form name="disc" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="price">قیمت کالا به تومان :</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="مثلا 2580000" name="price" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="t-per">درصد تخفیف دریافتی شما :</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="t-per" placeholder="مثلا 8" name="t-per" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="c-per">درصد تخفیف شما به مشتری :</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="c-per" placeholder="مثلا 6" name="c-per" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="count">تعداد کالا :</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="count" placeholder="مثلا 5" name="count">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="mcalculate()">محاسبه</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">ریست</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p id="error1" class="red"></p>
            <p id="error2" class="red"></p>
            <p id="error3" class="red"></p>
            <p id="error4" class="red"></p>
            <p id="error5" class="red"></p>
            <p id="error6" class="red"></p>
            <p id="error7" class="red"></p>
            <p id="error8" class="red"></p>
            <p id="calResult"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Comparing strings can produce unexpected results, use numbers for comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast all inputs that you want to use/compare as numbers to type `Number` first. `.value` always returns strings. You should also try to use dot notation instead of bracket notation whenever possible - reduces syntax noise.

```
var mainPrice = Number(document.forms.disc.price.value);
var productPercentage = Number(document.forms.disc.['t-per'].value);
var customerPercentage = Number(document.forms.disc.['c-per'].value);
var productCount = Number(document.forms.disc.count.value);
```